# How do I permanently removing a ban stored by Fail2Ban

Tags: apache2, iptables, firewall, fail2ban

I have two filters that have banned local addresses. I have added the addresses to ignoreip but the damage was done already and the bans are in place. Every time I reboot my computer I have to do an `iptables -L f2b-apache-auth` and then drop the two local addresses and again with the other filter.

I can't figure out where it is saving the bans and adding them back when I reboot. Is there a file stored somewhere where I can edit it and remove these addresses from those bans so they won't be added into iptables after every reboot?

And as a follow up question .. it is adding them in `iptables` as computer's names not ip addresses ... in other words ... its showing as "computer name" not `192.168.x.xxx` in the filter under the ignoreregex = I have added the ip addresses of the local machines that I want to not be effected... do I also have to add "computer name" to those entries also or would that cause the filter to fail?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bans are stored in a SQLite3 database in `/var/lib/fail2ban`. To open it you need the package `sqlite3` installed and if you want a GUI, use a tool like `sqliteman`.

The name of that database file is called:

```
/var/lib/fail2ban/fail2ban.sqlite3
```

Comment: Thanks you so much ... this is what I needed. After installing these programs I was also able to see how the data was stored and it answered my second question also ... the addresses are stored by IP so ... I do not have to worry about trying to add the computer name in the "ignore" part.

Answer (score 1):

No need for such a low-level approach / manually editing the DB.

With Fail2Ban before v0.8.8:

```
fail2ban-client get YOURJAILNAMEHERE actionunban IPADDRESSHERE
```

With Fail2Ban v0.8.8 and later:

```
fail2ban-client set YOURJAILNAMEHERE unbanip IPADDRESSHERE
```